# MVC is it possible to target blank + parameters

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

See this :

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "Func", new { controller = "MyControl" }, new { target = "_blank" })
```

It does what it is suposed to do, but what if i need my model, because here is the header of my function :

```
public ActionResult Func(model_1 m)
{ }
```

What i'm trying to do is open a new tab, and carry my model to this new tab... how can i do?

Comment: Remember, querystring has limitations. What if your model is  huge! You should pass a unique id /id(s) from which your second action method should be able to rebuild the Model as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload of Html.ActionLink helper method which allows you to pass route values.

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "Func", "MyControl" ,new { EmpId=1, EmpCode="E23" ,Age =23},
                                                                  new { target = "_blank" })
```

This will basically generate an anchor tag with href value with querystring formed from the route values you provided.

```
<a href="/Mycontrol/Func?EmpId=23&EmpCode=E23&Age=23">link</a>
```

Assuming you have a class with these 2 properties being used as the parameter of the action method

```
public class EmployeeVm
{
   public int EmpId { set;get;}
   public string EmpCode { set;get;}
   public int Age{ set;get;}
}
```

and this is being used as the type of your action method argument

```
public ActoinResult Func(EmployeeVm model)
{
  // To do : Return something
}
```

The model binder will be able to map the querystring values to the properties of the parameter object.

But remember, querystring's has limitations in how much data it can carry. Also **the above approach work for a lean-flat view model class**. It won't work for a complex viewmodel class where your properties are other classses /collection of other types.

In that case, The best solution is to pass a unique id / combination of Ids and use that to rebuild your model / view model in the second action method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("link", "Func", "MyControl" ,new { EmpId=1}, new { target = "_blank" })
```

and in your action method

```
public ActionResult Func(int empId)
{
  // to do  : Using empIdvalue, Get the View model /Model data
  // Ex : EmployeeVm emp = SomeService.GetEmployeeFromId(empId)

}
```

Assuming `SomeService.GetEmployeeFromId` accepts an employeeId and return an object of `EmployeeVm`. The method can query your db table to get the corresponding employee record for the id passed in and build the EmployeeVm object from that data.